# read .shp GIS on Java

Tags: dataset, java

I know that can sounds weird this thread. but if we are talking about a popular data base, we need to meet a way to upload .shp file to post gis using an API, batch files seems a terrible workaround. I tried Rjava but nothing, I tried GISserver, but his .war is not working. So, I don't know what I can do anymore. Any advice are very welcome.

Ps.: I'm using Java/Spring, if anyone knows an efficient solution to deal with these architecture are very welcome too.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Have you looked at geotools?

Comment: Not yet. I'll take a look. Did you used?

Comment: No, but colleagues of mine do.

Comment: See ArcGIS it has Java API for work with .shp files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at [geotools shapefile plugin](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/shape.html)?

Basically you need to add the maven dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
   <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
   <version>${geotools.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

And then you can easily follow the attached example

```
        File file = new File("example.shp");
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());

        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
        String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

        FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source =
                dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        Filter filter = Filter.INCLUDE; // ECQL.toFilter("BBOX(THE_GEOM, 10,20,30,40)")

        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> collection = source.getFeatures(filter);
        try (FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> features = collection.features()) {
            while (features.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = features.next();
                System.out.print(feature.getID());
                System.out.print(": ");
                System.out.println(feature.getDefaultGeometryProperty().getValue());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.](/help/referencing).